# Prevent iOS 11 from closing background apps?

Tags: ios

Since upgrading to iOS 11, I've noticed that apps running in the background are closed much more aggressively.

Two specific cases that are especially frustrating:

- Google Maps, which was in the middle of routing me, was closed and I almost missed my exit because it didn't give me a notification.
- WhatsApp is frequently closed, which stops notifications from showing up on the desktop app.

Is there anything I can do to prevent iOS from closing these apps?

(and for completeness: "background app refresh" is enabled for these apps, and this is on an iPhone 6)

Comment: It looks like Google Maps crashed. Does it happen often or was it a single instance?  I use App,etc, Google, & Waze maps often and don't recall them ever being closed while in use (on iOS 11). I can see WhatsApp being closed if you haven't received notifications recently.

Comment: @fsb — What would close WhatsApp? WhatsApp? IOS?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco iOS would close the app, most likely, if the app is no longer using any resources and there's other apps or system resources that require whatever WhatsApp is using.

Comment: This is still happening on 11.2.2. For example if you play music from the Amazon Music and turn off iPhone screen, the music continues playing. Pause playback from the "swipe up" control centre. Wait 1 minute. Amazon app has closed and playback cannot be resumed. Instead when pressing the play button in control centre the music starts from next track.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in iOS 11 and should be fixed with iOS 11.1
Most of the Apps are using the *BackgroundFetch* functionality, which is totally broken in iOS 11

Currently there is iOS 11.1 beta 4 released. It seems that Apple will release the final version within the delivery of the iPhone X.

If you want to have more technical details you can have a look at the technical topics in StackOverflow: [iOS11 swift silent push (background fetch, didReceiveRemoteNotification) is not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330053/ios11-swift-silent-push-background-fetch-didreceiveremotenotification-is-not)

---

**UPDATE 2017-10-31**

Just FYI: Apple released today iOS11.1 -> the issue should be now resolved from a operating system point of view.